# Get value separated by comma WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

How to get a value separated with comma. I used [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) for it. This is what I've tried.

```
$get_item_desc = get_post_meta ($post->ID, 'item_description', true); 
$arr = explode(",", $get_item_desc);
$item_string = '';
foreach($arr as $val){
        echo $get_items = $item_string.trim($val).' ';
}
```

Sample Input:

Item 1, Item 2, Item 3

Sample Output:

DESC-1: Item 1
DESC-2: Item 2
DESC-3: Item 3

Comment: What does the input value look like (the raw data from `get_post_meta()`), and what does the end result need to look like?

Comment: I don't really get what you want to do here, you get your meta like that `meta1,meta2,meta3` and want to display them like that `meta1, meta2, meta3` ?

Comment: the input value must be"Item 1, Item 2, Item 3" and the output must be "DESC-1: Item 1 DESC-2: Item2 DESC-3: Item3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sample input/output, you can use:

```
$get_item_desc = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'item_description', true); 
$arr = explode(',', $get_item_desc);
$i = 1;

foreach($arr as $val){
    echo 'DESC-' . $i . ': ' . trim($val) . ' ';
    $i++;
}
```